# Empty asp:BulletedList doesn't show up in html

Tags: asp.net, bulletedlist

I'm trying to add an empty asp:BulletedList to a page so I can run a jquery on it. But when I open the page the bulletlist doesn't show up.

Is there a trick to getting an empty asp:BulletedList to show up?

Comment: What are you expecting to be in the resulting HTML?  What's actually ending up there?  It's entirely possible that the control is smart enough to not render anything if it's empty, in which case you could just output explicitly what you need to be on the page.

Comment: if it's empty, what would show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty BulletedList like this:

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server">
</asp:BulletedList>
```

will not render into page HTML at all because it makes no sense much as `<UL>` element without `<LI>` elements.

But if you add at least one (even empty) list item:

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
</asp:BulletedList>
```

It will render as

```
<ul id="BulletedList1">
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There are cases where it does make sense to have an empty UL, such as when you're creating a drag-n-drop list of items from one list to another (e.g. jQuery's Sortable Connect lists). This is simply a case of the language trying to be *too* clever.